# jquery variable addicion issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with my variable adding itself to itself.

The variable starts off as `0`, then It'll add `1` to itself and then never do it again.
I wondered if anyone had any idea on how to fix this, as my major issue is that the variable **cannot** be global has more than one of these variables will be used. The table is 12x24, meaning there are alot of `td`.

Example:

> if you click in td:nth-child(1) that will use a different variable
>   compared to td:nth-child(5)

So heres my code so far ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaiyanToaster/xpmkmLj1/1/)):

jQuery:

```
$('table.masteries tr.p0 td').on('click', function(){
    i = 0
    s = $(this).find('p').text()
    current_max = parseInt(s.substr(s.length - 1))
    if (
        $(this).is($(':nth-child(1)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(2)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(3)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(4)'))
    ) {
        i = i + 1 /<-- the issue
        console.log(i) /<-- the issue
        $(this).closest('span').append(i); /<-- the issue
    } else if (
        $(this).is($(':nth-child(5)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(6)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(7)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(8)'))
    ) {

    } else if (
        $(this).is($(':nth-child(9)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(10)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(11)'))
        || $(this).is($(':nth-child(12)'))
    ) {

    }
});
```

Snippet of HTML:

```
<table class="masteries" border="1">
        <tr class="p0">
            <td><p><span>0</span>/1</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/4</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/4</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/1</p></td>

            <td><p><span>0</span>/2</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/2</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/2</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/2</p></td>

            <td><p><span>0</span>/1</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/3</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/3</p></td>
            <td><p><span>0</span>/1</p></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Every time you click, you are resetting "i" to = 0 and only increment it by 1. Thus, "i" can never be > 1.

Comment: get rid of all the `is(':nth-child')` and just use the index of the `<td>`. Will make code far simpler and easier to read

Comment: An aside - You can use `+=` to add things to themselves. `i += 5` is the same as `i = i + 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
i = 0
```

to

```
if(!i){
   i = 0;
}
```

So if `i` has already been set, it won't be reset to 0.

**Update**

You also need to change all instances of `i` to `this.i` since `i` is a local function variable that will be lost every time the callback function closes.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpmkmLj1/6/)

Comment: Hey there! I tried doing this (http://jsfiddle.net/SaiyanToaster/xpmkmLj1/5/) and I just get a console error saying that i isn't set.

Comment: @SaiyanToaster I updated my answer, it's because `i` is a local function variable